# How to specify write access to volume with fig

Tags: python, deployment, yaml, docker, fig

with docker -v option we can specify write access like below

```
docker run -d --name web -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

where `ro` means **readonly** access.

How can we do it with fig? if

```
pg:
  image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/postgres:9.1-1
web:
  image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/unicorn:0.0.2
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - .:/src
  links:
    - pg:server_pg
  command: /bin/bash -xe something.sh
```

in above example **:ro** in volumes section raise following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.main", line 39, in main
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.docopt_command", line 21, in sys_dispatch
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.command", line 31, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.docopt_command", line 24, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.command", line 50, in perform_command
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.docopt_command", line 27, in perform_command
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.cli.main", line 306, in up
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.project", line 131, in up
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.service", line 173, in recreate_containers
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.service", line 195, in recreate_container
  File "/code/build/fig/out00-PYZ.pyz/fig.service", line 225, in start_container
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: You might be better off raising an issue on Fig's github page: https://github.com/docker/fig/issues

Comment: Oh, you already have - it looks like they're working on it: https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/129

Comment: This very is issue has been resolved since https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/260